# How can you change the anchor point in Paint 3D so that a rectangle rotates around one of its sides?

Tags: paint-3d

When I take a rectangle and paste it into Paint 3D, the "vertical" (up the page) axis of rotation is through its centre. How can I move this axis to include, say, the rectangle's left side?

Comment: I think we don't have option for pivot point or anchor point change option in Paint 3D.

Comment: Thanks, @Vikas. If this is so and you post it as an answer, I will accept it. I have now [asked](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/79996/a-program-in-which-one-can-paste-a-2d-shape-from-powerpoint-make-it-3d-and-cha) on SoftwareRecs.SE for recommendations of a program that can do this, given that Paint 3D can't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use Paint 3D but since it's available with Windows 10, I tried to see if it's possible to shift pivot/anchor point. But I couldn't find any option in the interface itself.

There's official [A Guide to Paint 3D](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWs4_NfqMtoycRV4YeGlaLePsD5cyRPrN) on YouTube by Windows channel. I couldn't find such an option for flexible rotation in those tutorials.

I further saw a few basic tutorials on YouTube about rotation of 2D and 3D shapes in Paint 3D but nothing much was revealed. A few articles about the same I went through didn't mention something like this.

So I feel this feature of shifting the pivot/anchor to some other edge or corner is **not possible**. Something which we see in a dedicated 3D program like Blender.

You might just want to go for some other workarounds. Something like rotate it the way it is possible. Then change the position of rectangle. Maybe create a temporary shape for a 'guide'. Something like this:

[image]

Above example is for 2D. I think you can do similar 'trick' in 3D rotation too, along the edge. Something like this:

[image]

**Detailed Example:**

Let's say this is a front view of a Door like structure. Blue Door to yellow wall.

[image]

Now I want it to open this door. So I want it to rotate on left edge as axis. But like your problem, Paint 3D doesn't give you this option. You can only rotate it from center. Just like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, we have to fix it. So I will use the wall edge as a guide and move door's left side towards it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I think the method of putting a dot outside the rectangle to change the centre or axis of rotation requires that it be put a long way outside it if the aim is to move the centre or axis all the way to the shape's perimeter. I can't quite follow where the axes of rotation move to in your animations.

Comment: @ruffle I quite didn't get your last sentence. Actually the axes of rotation is still in the center, the idea is just to manually move it to that point, so the end result looks like it has been rotated on left edge.

Also, I put that blue dot randomly. So I had to move the rectangle a lot more in 2 directions. You can place it on the edge of the rectangle in initial situation.

Comment: If you really want to try this or think this can be helpful, I might need to know more what you want to achieve with this.

Comment: I would like to be able to cut a 2D rectangle from Powerpoint, paste it into a program, turn it into a 3D object, change one axis of rotation so that it's along an edge of the rectangle, paste back into Powerpoint, and then animate so that I get a "door opening" effect. The step that's causing the difficulty is changing the axis of rotation. Everything else is doable using Paint 3D.

Comment: @ruffle you don't want it to rotate it in Paint 3D? You just want to change the axis? Secondly, I don't know PowerPoint much. So I definitely can't comment about how combining PowerPoint and Paint 3D would work.

Comment: My point was to help you rotate the rectangle in such a way that final result looks like it is rotated along it's left side, not center. It might not appear fully in my GIF, but if you want I can further demonstrate it. Further, it won't be very perfect. We are just using a workaround. It won't snap perfectly. There would be a bit alignment differences.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I don't just need to put the rectangle into its final position - I actually need it to rotate about an axis. This is easy enough to do in Powerpoint using the "turntable" animation, but only once an axis has been defined, and the default is to have the axis run through the rectangle's centre.

Comment: @ruffle oh. I got it. That's beyond my knowledge. I don't even know if PowerPoint understands the 3D object copied from Paint 3D. Since you really need to change the axis, I really think you will need some other solution for this.

Comment: @ruffle if this is still unsolved try to rotate of a group which has 2 halves: 1) the wanted visible door and 2) a fully transparent another as wide piece.